# How can you add an ID to dynamically generated href?

Tags: javascript, html

how can you add an ID to a link generated like this?

```
function addElement(list, pos) {
    var linkUrl = productList.products[pos].productLink;
    var linkItem = document.createElement('a');
    linkItem.setAttribute('href', linkUrl);
```

The previous code generates the following link

```
<a href="***/details.page?productId=3"><img src="***/topseller_main_en_1.png"></a>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
function addElement(list, pos) { 
    var linkUrl = productList.products[pos].productLink; 
    var linkItem = document.createElement("a"); 
    if (linkItem){
        linkItem.id = "foo";
        linkItem.href = linkUrl;
    }
}
```

You can also do this in jQuery like this:

```
function addElement(list, pos) { 
    var linkUrl = productList.products[pos].productLink; 
    var linkItem = document.createElement("a"); 
    if (linkItem){
        linkItem.attr({ id : "foo", href : linkItem });
    }
}
```

Here's an even shorter way:

```
$("<a>").attr({ id : "foo", href : linkUrl });
```

Then just append it to an element in the document.

Comment: Or, even shorter in jQuery, `var linkItem = $('<a>').attr({id : "foo", href : linkItem});`